# What are the actual rules of method overriding in PHP?

Tags: php, overriding

```
class A {
    function m1($a) {
        echo "from A";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function m1() {
        echo "from B";
    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->m1();
```

I thought this wasn't supposed to work because according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends):

> When overriding methods, the **parameter signature should remain the
>   same or PHP will generate an E_STRICT level error**. This does not apply
>   to the constructor, which allows overriding with different parameters.

If I understand correctly, required parameters must be the same when extending a class and overriding one of its methods. Isn't this true? What are the actual rules of method overriding in PHP? Please elaborate.

Comment: `During overriding, required parameters must be the same.` Where did you get this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I am wrong, then.

Comment: "When overriding methods, the parameter signature should remain the same or PHP will generate an E_STRICT level error." [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: It does: https://ideone.com/JzeZJF

Comment: Doesn't show in mine. it's PHP 5.6.30. i tried `error_reporting(E_ALL)` , too, just in case.

Comment: Ok, it worked as expected after i changed error reporting in php.ini file. i wonder why it didn't work with `error_reporting(E_ALL)`.